# Cannot click on List item

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I Am Extremely new to Adroid!
I have a login page, when i click login it gives the users a listview 
After which when I click on the row should make a request to the server and login according to those credentials.

I have made my list view using a custom adapter but i cannot click on the items. 
Just need some help with how to make it clickable. 
Before when I was using a simple adapter, the list was clickable and my object was returned.

When I de-bug, I Can see that it hits the "AgencyListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()" line but does not make the items clickable. 
My listview xml is set to clickable. 
P.S I am not extending ListActivity as I Am doing all this in one activity.

```
 private void showList(final String deviceId, final String TokenId) {

     findViewById(R.id.emailText).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      findViewById(R.id.passwordText).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      findViewById(R.id.loginButton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      findViewById(R.id.listview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      final ListView AgencyListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
       //ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, agencyList);
       // ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (this,agencyList, android.R.layout.item_row, 
           //     new String[] { "Eid", "Ename", "Eaddress" }, 
             //   new int[] {  R.id.TextView1,R.id.TextView2,R.id.TextView3 });
              //  setListAdapter(adapter);
         //  AgencyListview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


          AgencyAdapter aa = new AgencyAdapter(this, R.id.listview, list) {
            public boolean isEnabled(int position){
                return false;
            }
        };
        AgencyListview.setAdapter(aa);



AgencyListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
          Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + " at position:" + position);
        Object o = AgencyListview.getItemAtPosition(position);
        o.toString();

        url= "http://10.0.1.41/api/Account/select?deviceid="+deviceId+"&TokenId="+TokenId+"&userid=a29a5dba-d8f9-474b-92ca-b5dcadcc6390&agencyid=62b904fa-b38f-4686-b2e4-d748fa129c50";  
        new ServiceTask(){

            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            System.out.println( "NEW MULTI***" + result);
            try {
                 userObject = new JSONObject(result);
                 HasMultiple = "false";
                convertJson(result);
                 saveSession( AgencyName);
                  startMain();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
            }.execute(url);
      }
    });
}
```

This is my Custom Adapter :

```
   class AgencyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AgencyItems> {
    private Context context;
    private List<AgencyItems> items;

    public AgencyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<AgencyItems> items){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;
        if(v==null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.agency_row, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textViewItemName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.agency_label_text);
            viewHolder.textViewItemValue = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.agency_value_text);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        final int currentPosition = position;
        holder.textViewItemName.setText(items.get(currentPosition).getName());
        holder.textViewItemValue.setText(items.get(currentPosition).getValue());

        return v;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {

    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewItemName;
        public TextView textViewItemValue;
    }
}
```

This is my agency_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_padding"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_padding"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >   
       <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/agency_label_text"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
          android:text="Default"
          android:layout_weight="0.3"
         android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"

    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/agency_value_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Default value"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
     </LinearLayout>


enter code here
```

Comment: Can you add your `agency_row.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to react to an item tap in the list, not react to the list itself being tapped.

For this, you need to put a listener in the getView method of the adapter, not the the list itself as you have depicted here:

```
AgencyListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
          Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + " at position:" + position);
        Object o = AgencyListview.getItemAtPosition(position);
        o.toString();

        url= "http://10.0.1.41/api/Account/select?deviceid="+deviceId+"&TokenId="+TokenId+"&userid=a29a5dba-d8f9-474b-92ca-b5dcadcc6390&agencyid=62b904fa-b38f-4686-b2e4-d748fa129c50";  
        new ServiceTask(){

            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            System.out.println( "NEW MULTI***" + result);
            try {
                 userObject = new JSONObject(result);
                 HasMultiple = "false";
                convertJson(result);
                 saveSession( AgencyName);
                  startMain();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
            }.execute(url);
      }
    });
}
```

Should be:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    if(v==null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.agency_row, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textViewItemName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.agency_label_text);
        viewHolder.textViewItemValue = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.agency_value_text);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    final int currentPosition = position;
    holder.textViewItemName.setText(items.get(currentPosition).getName());
    holder.textViewItemValue.setText(items.get(currentPosition).getValue());

    // put your click listener here
    v.OnClickListener{

      @Override
      public void onClick(
        // example
        activity.methodToExecute();
      }
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: IF i do that, I get a null pointer exception, on the on click listener.

Comment: And nothing loads up. Is there any good tutorial I can follow?

Comment: Likely because you are using a resource that is not available in the adapter.  For this, you will want to call back to the Activity that you are scoping the adapter in - where the resource exists.  You will need to inject the activity into your adapter to do that.

Comment: Also, while James' answer is correct, this way gives you considerably more control over the process.

Comment: I Am sorry could you explain how to do that, this is just my first couple of weeks and most of what you said seems so vague.

Comment: @user1574381 I have updated my answer to reflect using the activity based method.  Inject your activity in the adapter's constructor and use in conjunction with a module level variable.

Comment: Thank you for the direction, is there some place where i can learn more about activity injection. and what would my  activity.methodToExecute(); do?

Comment: Just put the code you were trying to execute in the AgencyListview.setOnItemClickListener onItemClick event into the activity method.  to inject simply use activity in place of context in your constructor.  Since you are using a specific method from a specific activity, you will want a strongly typed object (the specific activity class)  You can get the context from the class so you can appease your superconstructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to have `android:clickable="true"` in your xml file.  A lot of times, this will actually mess things up.  Try removing it.

Comment: Yes.  Setting the `onItemClickListener` will do the work for you by setting each row as clickable.

Comment: This method will work, but if you are going to the trouble to create a custom adapter, then make that adapter universal and handle the events for each item in the adapter.  Otherwise, you will have to replicate the events for each implementation.